# Subtract value of column based on another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, subtraction

I have a big dataframe (the following is an example)

| country | value |
| --- | --- |
| portugal | 86 |
| germany | 20 |
| belgium | 21 |
| Uk | 81 |
| portugal | 77 |
| UK | 87 |

I want to subtract values by 60 whenever the country is portugal or UK, the dataframe should look like (Python)

| country | value |
| --- | --- |
| portugal | 26 |
| germany | 20 |
| belgium | 21 |
| Uk | 21 |
| portugal | 17 |
| UK | 27 |

Comment: I tried this but it takes a long time to load so I don't know if it works .........df.loc[df.country == "portugal", "value"] = df.value - 60.............df.loc[df.country == "Uk", "value"] = df.value - 60

Answer (score 2):

IUUC, use [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) on the lowercase country string to check if the values is in a reference list, then slice the dataframe with [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for in place modification:

```
df.loc[df['country'].str.lower().isin(['portugal', 'uk']), 'value'] -= 60
```

output:

```
    country  value
0  portugal     26
1   germany     20
2   belgium     21
3        Uk     21
4  portugal     17
5        UK     27
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
In [1621]: import numpy as np

In [1622]: df['value'] = np.where(df['country'].str.lower().isin(['portugal', 'uk']), df['value'] - 60, df['value'])

In [1623]: df
Out[1623]: 
    country  value
0  portugal     26
1   germany     20
2   belgium     21
3        Uk     21
4  portugal     17
5        UK     27
```